# Trying to scroll through CT slices

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am using code slightly altered (changed index) from https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/event_handling/image_slices_viewer.html

Unfortunately the output is a static image. I am using jupyter notebook (the functions after class are indented over in my actual code)

```
class IndexTracker(object):
    def __init__(self, ax, X):
        self.ax = ax
        ax.set_title('use scroll wheel to navigate images')

        self.X = X
        self.slices, rows, cols = X.shape
        self.ind = self.slices//2

        self.im = ax.imshow(self.X[self.ind, :, :])
        self.update()

    def onscroll(self, event):
        print("%s %s" % (event.button, event.step))
        if event.button == 'up':
            self.ind = (self.ind + 1) % self.slices
        else:
            self.ind = (self.ind - 1) % self.slices
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        self.im.set_data(self.X[self.ind, :, :])
        self.ax.set_ylabel('slice %s' % self.ind)
        self.im.axes.figure.canvas.draw()
```

How I am then viewing the 3D images

```
cube = dicom_cbct_view(test_dir, trim_factor=trim_factor)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)


tracker = IndexTracker(ax, cube)


fig.canvas.mpl_connect('scroll_event', tracker.onscroll)
plt.show()
```

Output (cant scroll)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Sorry everyone. I am dumb. I needed

```
%matplotlib qt
```

so below worked

```
%matplotlib qt 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)


tracker = IndexTracker(ax, cube)


fig.canvas.mpl_connect('scroll_event', tracker.onscroll)

plt.show()
```